# What do I need to set up two DVI monitors on a 2011 Mac mini?

Tags: mac-mini

As a software developer who recently bought an iPhone, I knew it was just a matter of time before I started dicking around in the iOS apps space. Today Apple released a new line of Mac minis and I am going to buy one. I'd like to just buy a KVM switch and flip between my current two monitor PC setup and the Mac. What kind of adapters do I need for the Mac mini to be able to take two DVI outs?

I've been told that I can use a mini DisplayPort to DVI adapter with the Thunderbolt port then just a HDMI to DVI in the HDMI port, is that possible?

Comment: It is possible.

Answer (score 4):

> I've been told that I can use a mini DisplayPort to DVI adapter with the Thunderbolt port then just a HDMI to DVI in the HDMI port, is that possible?

That's what I do with a 2010 mini (MDP instead of TB).

Yes, it works perfectly.

The tricky part comes if you want *three* monitors. For that, you need to be sure to buy the video-boosted Mini model that has discrete graphics, or use a (slow) USB video adapter for the third screen. But for two, any modern mini is fine out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

> I've been told that I can use a Mini Display Port to DVI adaptor with the thunderbolt port then just a HDMI to DVI in the HDMI port, is that possible?

This should be theoretically possible. The only other option I can think of is to get a splitter for the thunderbolt port and get 2 dvi adapters.

Answer (score -1):

I was just looking into hooking up two displays to my yet to arrive Macbook Air and found a [Mini DisplayPort | Thunderbolt to DVI (2 DVI Output) Converter.](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=101&cp_id=10114&cs_id=1011409&p_id=8118&seq=1&format=2)

I don't see why this wouldn't work for the Mac mini as well.

Comment: How would this meet the KVM requirement to have input as well as output? (i.e. it might be a better answer on a how to split one thunderbolt to two displays which is different than two macs to the same display.)